# How can I install Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, photoshop

I have some problems with installing Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04 through Wine.

My installation starts fine but at end of the charging it displaying an error.

Comment: it is custom to google the error and see what turns up or if to include the error message in your question. But imo wine aint worth it. Get a genuine copy of windows and use virtualbox to install windows and CS6 or create a dual boot. Or do as most of us: learn to use GIMP.

Comment: It would be better to post a screenshot of your error.

Comment: @muru - The one you've listed is for 14. I got one for 16.

Comment: @AndroidDev any substantial difference?

Comment: @muru - No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try and create a virtual windows machine with virtualbox. You can download virtualbox with apt-get.

For the virtual machine image go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/ and download a free virtual machine. It's basically a fully functional copy of Windows that developers can use, but it works exactly like a normal Windows copy.

After you downloaded everything and installed VirtualBox just double click of the Windows virtual machine package and it should start up automatically.